# Changing a big video on click of smaller ones

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a responsive video gallery where you can click on a selection of 12 different videos and have it pop up on a bigger video above the smaller 12. I have the javascript started, but I'm running into some walls (I'm still new to javascript).

Here's the HTML

```
    <div id="gallery">
        <div id="mainvideo">
            <video id="displayvideo" src="#" autoplay></video>
            <div id="mainvideowords">
                <h2>#</h2>
                <h3>#</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="videogallery">
            <div class="littlevideo">
                <video src="#"></video>
                <div class="littlevideowords">
                    <h4>#</h4>
                    <p>#</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here's what I have so far on the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".littlevideo").click(function() {
            var video = $(this).closest("div").find("video").attr("src")
            $('#displayvideo').attr("src",video);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm also seeing some other issues of the video not even showing up. Should I use an iframe instead? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `var video = $(this).closest(".image").find("video").attr("src")` No element at `html` at Question has `.image` `.className` set?

Comment: @guest271314, whoops, you're right. I updated it.

Comment: Not certain what issue is? `javascript` at Question appears to return expected result?

Comment: The issue I'm running into now is that no video shows up at all... even without the js. Don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Is `src` of `<video>` set to a valid path to a a video file? What does `Network` tab log at browser at request for video resource?

Comment: It's set to a youtube link, now I'm starting to think that that's not something I can actually do.